# Delphi Indy Ping Error 10040 after upgrade from XE3 to XE4

Tags: delphi, indy10

I created a Ping function that utilizes the Indy TIdIcmpClient object.  It has worked flawlessly for years.  After upgrading from XE3 to XE4 the same code is now generating error 10040 (Message too long).

I read other posts concerning this error and the proposed solutions, but none of them have worked with 100% success.

I have reduced packet size to 32, 24, 12 and even 0, but still get the 10040 error.

I tried using the optional parameter "Buffer" which worked a little bit but occasionally causes other exceptions.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Here's my code:

```
function Ping(Host: String;Timeout: Integer;ShowError: Boolean; out ErrorText: String): Boolean;
var
  IdIcmpClient1: TIdIcmpClient;
  Reply: TReplyStatusTypes;
  ErrorFlag: Boolean;
  ABuffer: String;
begin
  Result:=False;
  ErrorText:='Success';
  ErrorFlag:=False;
  Reply:=rsEcho;
  ABuffer:=Host+StringOfChar(' ',255);
  IdIcmpClient1:=TIdIcmpClient.Create;
  IdIcmpClient1.PacketSize:=32;
  IdIcmpClient1.Host:=Host;
  IdIcmpClient1.ReceiveTimeout:=Timeout;
  try
    try
      IdIcmpClient1.Ping(ABuffer);
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        ErrorFlag:=True;
        ErrorText:=E.Message;
        if ShowError then MessageDlg('Ping Error: '+E.Message, mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
      end;
    end;
    if not ErrorFlag then
    begin
      try
        Reply:=IdIcmpClient1.ReplyStatus.ReplyStatusType;
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          ErrorFlag:=True;
          ErrorText:=E.Message;
          if ShowError then MessageDlg('Ping Reply Error: '+ErrorText, mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
        end;
      end;
    end;
    if not ErrorFlag then
    begin
      Result:=Reply=rsEcho;
      if not Result then
      begin
        case Reply of
          rsEcho: ErrorText:='rsEcho';
          rsError: ErrorText:='rsError';
          rsTimeOut: ErrorText:='rsTimeOut';
          rsErrorUnreachable: ErrorText:='rsErrorUnreachable';
          rsErrorTTLExceeded: ErrorText:='rsErrorTTLExceeded';
          rsErrorPacketTooBig: ErrorText:='rsErrorPacketTooBig';
          rsErrorParameter: ErrorText:='rsErrorParameter';
          rsErrorDatagramConversion: ErrorText:='rsErrorDatagramConversion';
          rsErrorSecurityFailure: ErrorText:='rsErrorSecurityFailure';
          rsSourceQuench: ErrorText:='rsSourceQuench';
          rsRedirect: ErrorText:='rsRedirect';
          rsTimeStamp: ErrorText:='rsTimeStamp';
          rsInfoRequest: ErrorText:='rsInfoRequest';
          rsAddressMaskRequest: ErrorText:='rsAddressMaskRequest';
          rsTraceRoute: ErrorText:='rsTraceRoute';
          rsMobileHostReg: ErrorText:='rsMobileHostReg';
          rsMobileHostRedir: ErrorText:='rsMobileHostRedir';
          rsIPv6WhereAreYou: ErrorText:='rsIPv6WhereAreYou';
          rsIPv6IAmHere: ErrorText:='rsIPv6IAmHere';
          rsSKIP: ErrorText:='rsSkip';
        else
          ErrorText:='Unknown';
        end;
        if ShowError then MessageDlg('Ping Error: '+ErrorText, mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    IdIcmpClient1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Thanks for your time,

Tad

Answer (score 1):

Fixes for `TIdIcmpClient` are already in the works but have not been released yet, and I don't have an ETA for that release at this time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , It's now Feb, 2014 and I'm using C++ Builder XE5 with Indy10 `TIdIcmpClient Ping()` and this problem is still present. Are you guys working on this or has an update/fix already been released?

Comment: Sorry, but I have not had **ANY** free time to work on this issue yet. Between my day job and my family, I am swamped and just don't have the kind of spare time I used to have. It is still on my TODO list. I made some changes to `TIdIcmpClient` but have not tested them yet.

Answer (score 1):

you must set ABuffer, e.g.:

```
            Host := 'some.server.net';
            PacketSize := 24;
            ReceiveTimeout := 200;
            ABuffer := Host + StringOfChar(' ', 255);
            Ping(ABuffer);
```

Jan

Comment: I can confirm that this worked with the IDICMPClient component, at least until Remy and his team release their own fixes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am already doing just that (it's in the code above). This works most of the time, but occasionally causes an exception.